# Prove that: $\frac{bc}{a^2+1}+\frac{ac}{b^2+1}+\frac{ab}{c^2+1}\leq \frac{3}{4}$

Tags: inequality, summation, symmetric-polynomials, a.m.-g.m.-inequality, cauchy-schwarz-inequality

Given three positive numbers a,b,c satisfying $$a^2+b^2+c^2=1$$ Prove that: $$\frac{bc}{a^2+1}+\frac{ac}{b^2+1}+\frac{ab}{c^2+1}\leq \frac{3}{4}$$
The things I have done so far:
$$\sum \limits_{cyc}\frac{bc}{a^2+1}=\sum \limits_{cyc}\frac{bc}{2a^2+b^2+c^2}\leq \sum \limits_{cyc}\frac{bc}{2ab+2ac}$$
$$=\sum \limits_{cyc}\frac{bc}{2a(b+c)}\leq \frac{1}{4}\sum \limits_{cyc}\frac{(b+c)^2}{2a(b+c)}=\frac{1}{4}\sum \limits_{cyc}\frac{b+c}{2a}$$
$$=\frac{1}{8}.\frac{\sum \limits_{cyc}bc(b+c)}{abc}=\frac{1}{8}.\frac{\sum \limits_{cyc}bc(b+c)+3abc}{abc}-\frac{3}{8}$$
$$=\frac{1}{8}.\frac{(a+b+c)(ab+bc+ca)}{abc}-\frac{3}{8}$$
$$\leq \frac{1}{8}.\frac{\sqrt{3(a^2+b^2+c^2)}(a^2+b^2+c^2)}{abc}-\frac{3}{8}$$
$$=\frac{\sqrt{3}}{8abc}-\frac{3}{8}$$
I don't know what to do anymore.

Comment: I would use that $\frac{bc}{a^2+1}\le \frac{2(b^2+c^2)}{1+a^2}=\frac{2(1-a^2)}{1+a^2}$ and so on.

Comment: [Approach0](https://approach0.xyz/search/?q=%24%5Cfrac%7Bbc%7D%7Ba%5E2%2B1%7D%2B%5Cfrac%7Bac%7D%7Bb%5E2%2B1%7D%2B%5Cfrac%7Bab%7D%7Bc%5E2%2B1%7D%5Cle%5Cfrac%7B3%7D%7B4%7D%24&p=1) finds a dupe immediately. Downvote to any "trusted" user who didn't search.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By AM-GM and C-S we obtain:
$$\sum_{cyc}\frac{bc}{a^2+1}=\sum_{cyc}\frac{bc}{2a^2+b^2+c^2}\leq\frac{1}{4}\sum_{cyc}\frac{(b+c)^2}{a^2+b^2+a^2+c^2}\leq$$
$$\leq\frac{1}{4}\sum_{cyc}\left(\frac{b^2}{a^2+b^2}+\frac{c^2}{a^2+c^2}\right)=\frac{1}{4}\sum_{cyc}\left(\frac{b^2}{a^2+b^2}+\frac{a^2}{b^2+a^2}\right)=\frac{3}{4}.$$

Comment: How do you get
$$
\frac{(b+c)^2}{a^2+b^2+a^2+c^2}\leq \left(\frac{b^2}{a^2+b^2}+\frac{c^2}{a^2+c^2}\right) \, ?
$$

Comment: @Diger It's the Cauchy-Schwarz inequality.

Comment: Sorry. Can you elaborate a bit? The only thing I come up with is w.l.g. $c<b$ thus
$$
\frac{(b+c)^2}{a^2+b^2+a^2+c^2}\leq \frac{2(b^2+c^2)}{2(a^2+c^2)} =\left(\frac{b^2}{a^2+c^2}+\frac{c^2}{a^2+c^2}\right)
$$

Comment: @Diger Just by C-S  $(a^2+b^2+a^2+c^2)\left(\frac{b^2}{a^2+b^2}+\frac{c^2}{a^2+c^2}\right)\geq(b+c)^2.$

Comment: ah -.- yeah thanks!

Comment: You are welcome! Good luck!